# File session driver not working properly on production (Laravel on shared hosting)

Tags: laravel, session, production-environment, shared-hosting

When using session on my local environment all worked ok, but when I publish the site in a shared hosting I started noticing some strange behaviours in the app. After a while I realized it has to do with the session and specifically I noticed that when I was working on my local environment the storage/framework/sessions folder only had 1 file that keep updating on any change but then on production I start monitoring the same folder and I realized that on any change instead of updating the file (or creating a new one and deleting the other) it was creating a new file but also keeping the old files making the app start acting in a wrong way.

Is this normal or should it be only 1 file per session as it was in the local environment?

### Update

After login the user the app ask to select the business they want to work and also they can change between business after, to store the business they choose I use the session and there is where the problem pop, after every change on that property of the session it creates a new session file without deleting the old one. Again when I do exactly the same thing locally it works but for some reason on the shared hosting it doesn't.

### SOLUTION

After days of trying to figure it out, I just figure out the solution.

Instead of using the Global Helpers of Laravel for storing the data I did it throw the request and apparently that work it out.

So basically instead of doing this:

`session('clienteElegido' => $client);`

I change it for this:

`$request->session()->put('clienteElegido',$client);` 
I still don't understand what's the difference and why it was working fine in my local environment and not in the share host but its working now like that so all good.

Thank you for all the quick replies.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... often if new sessions keep getting spawned there is some cookie issue, can you clear your cookies for this site and try again?

Comment: Thank you... I deleted all the cookies for the site and still the same thing, files keep spawning on every change. I think for some reason internally laravel is not deleting the old file as it was doing it in my local environment.

Comment: it doesn't delete them automatically in that way and for all it knows the session that file belongs to is still being used, if there is a new file there is a new session ... if there was an issue with the session cookie then the server isn't receiving that cookie so there is no session identifier so it has to create a new session ... that is why the first thought is a cookie issue of some sort, even configured wrong perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Try clearning cache, route, config and view

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

and let's see if your session issue will be fixed.

Comment: Still having the same problem.